# Checkbox function on true value still executes when value is false

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

In my Chrome extension, I have a toggle switch which is essentially a check box. When I switch it on and make the checked value true, it performs a certain function and when I switch it off it performs another function but the problem is when its switched off the function for when its switched on is still working and I want to be able to turn it off. What am I doing wrong?

**popup.js(Where switch is checked for true or false)**

```
const toggle = document.getElementById('switch');
const checkedAttr = document.createAttribute('checked');

toggle.addEventListener('click', () => {
    toggle.checked ? toggleChecked() : toggleUnchecked();
});

function toggleChecked() {
    chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, function(tabs) {
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {switchStatus: "on"}, function(response) {
            if(response.switchStatus === "on"){
                //alert("Success")
            }
        })
    })
}

function toggleUnchecked() {
    chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, function(tabs) {
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {switchStatus: "off"}, function(response) {
            if(response.switchStatus === "off"){
                //alert("Success")
            }
        })
    })
}
```

**content.js(where the functions occur)**

```
// Receiving message from popup.js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
      if (request.switchStatus === "on") {

        // Getting all text elements
        const allText = document.querySelectorAll('h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, p, li, td, caption, span, a');
        const colors = ['#ffadad', '#ffd6a5', '#fdffb6', '#caffbf', '#bdb2ff', '#9fdfff'];
        const findFontModal = 'findfont.html'

        // Loop through all text elements-
        // to be able to manipulate each individual one
        for (let i = 0; i < allText.length; i++) {

            //ON HOVER
            allText[i].addEventListener('mouseover', async () => {
                allText[i].style.backgroundColor = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
                allText[i].style.cursor = "pointer";
            });

            allText[i].addEventListener('mouseout', async () => {
                allText[i].style.backgroundColor = null;
            });

            //ON MOUSE CLICK
            allText[i].addEventListener('click', async (event) => {
              const showModal = async () => {
                const modal = document.createElement('dialog');
              
                modal.setAttribute(
                  "style",`
                  border: none;
                  border-radius:20px;
                  background-color:#fafafa;
                  position: absolute;
                  z-index:10000000000000;
                  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 0px 18px 50px -10px;
                  `);
              
                  modal.innerHTML = 
                  `
                  <iframe id="popup-content" scrolling="no" style="height:155px; width:347px; z-index:10000000000000;" frameBorder="0"></iframe>
                  `;

                  modal.style.top = event.pageY+"px";
                  modal.style.left = event.pageX+"px";
              
                  document.body.appendChild(modal);
                  const dialog = document.querySelector("dialog");
                  dialog.show();

                  document.body.addEventListener('click', () => {
                    document.body.removeChild(modal);
                    dialog.close();
                  });
              
                  const iframe = document.getElementById("popup-content");
                  iframe.src = chrome.extension.getURL("findfont.html")
              }

                // Load in HTML file
                fetch(chrome.runtime.getURL(findFontModal))
                  .then(r => r.text())
                  .then(html => {
                    showModal();
                });
            });
        }

        sendResponse({status: "done"});
        return;
      }

      // When toggle switch is unchecked
      else if (request.switchStatus === "off") {
        const allText = document.querySelectorAll('h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, p, li, td, caption, span, a');
        for (let i = 0; i < allText.length; i++) {
            allText[i].style.backgroundColor = null;
        }

        sendResponse({status: "done"});
      }
    }
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The toggle status should be stored in [chrome storage](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/storage/), so the checkbox state will persist when popup is repeatedly opened/closed. Assuming this is the case, the popup should function correctly as given.

There are, however, two separate things I recommend addressing in the content script:

1. the event handlers for mouseover/out/click are currently being added when (and every time) a message is received, but not removed on the "off" action, which is why they occur even after "off" message has been received.

One way to fix this is to separate the event listener registration from the point in time when messages are received. I have added an example below, where I use a boolean variable as a way to know if event should be performed or not ("on" or "off"), then flip this variable based on the received message. The event listener is added only once to each target element, and never removed, but each handler does nothing when flag is in "off" state (will explain this last part in next code block).

```js
let toggleIsOn = false;
const elementIsReady = "special-flag-xyz-put-something-unique-here"

// Receiving message from popup.js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
        // if there are other messages, review this
        toggleIsOn = request.switchStatus === "on";
    }
);

function registerEventHandlers() {
    const allText = document.querySelectorAll('h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, p, li, td, caption, span, a');

    for (let i = 0; i < allText.length; i++) {
        const element = allText[i];
        // mark each element with attribute to know the event
        // actions have been applied, to prevent registering
        // these handlers multiple times
        if (!element.hasAttribute(elementIsReady)) {
            element.addEventListener('mouseover', onMouseOver);
            element.addEventListener('mouseout', onMouseOut);
            element.addEventListener('click', onClick);
            element.setAttribute(elementIsReady, true);
        }
    }
}
```

Note in registering the event handlers I am also adding a special attribute to indicate the handlers have been added, to prevent registering the same handlers multiple times on the same element. The value can be anything sufficiently unique that is unlikely to occur as a DOM node attribute naturally.

Specify the event behavior for each event in respective functions. Note when toggle is in "off" state, the handler simply returns, i.e. "does nothing", and in the "on" case the event behavior will execute:

```js
async function onMouseOver(event) {
    if (!toggleIsOn) return;
    console.log(`mouse over: ${event.target.innerText}`);
}

async function onMouseOut(event) {
    if (!toggleIsOn) return;
    console.log(`mouse out: ${event.target.innerText}`);
}

async function onClick(event) {
    if (!toggleIsOn) return;
    console.log(`element click! ${event.target.innerText}`);
    // put the open modal logic here, etc.
}
```

The second point to address in the content script is *when to query the page for allText nodes* since it is no longer connected to the point in time when messages are received:

2. It would be sufficient to call `registerEventHandlers()` once on page load, if the goal was to only handle server-side rendered pages. This is unlikely the case. For single-page apps that dynamically modify the DOM, the event listeners are lost on DOM changes, and not added to new nodes generated after page load, unless `registerEventHandlers()` is called again whenever the DOM changes.

The way to address this issue is to use [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver), which allows watching dynamic changes in the DOM. Here is an example:

```js
// run once when script is loaded to setup the observer
// wrapping this in a "constructor" to illustrate that point
(function constructor() {
    const observer = new MutationObserver(registerEventHandlers);
    observer.observe(document.body, {subtree: true, childList: true});
}())
```

Using this strategy will allow the extension to work also on single-page apps. Since nodes are marked against re-registering event listeners multiple times, as explained earlier, that will not occur even when using a mutation observer: the script iteratively looks for text nodes that do not have the listeners yet, and adds them once as they are discovered.

Comment: This is working all fine and dandy, the only problem is, the chrome.storage you were talking about actually hasn't been/isn't working all this time. Whenever I close the popup and reopen it the switch is automatically off even though the functionality is still working.

Comment: Ah ok, look at the guide I linked for how to set a value in the storage and get it, then use that to persist the toggle state: get the state from storage when popup loads, the set it every time the toggle changes. If you have issue getting it to work, there should be existing examples here on SO.

Comment: Alright yeah, I was able to figure it out. Thanks man